# Why nest js param id is undefined?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Here's what the project directory looks like.
I'm currently using yarn berry for the monorepo and there are two packages.
One is the apps where the applications are located and packages where some shared libraries and modules are stored.

`- apps

- bff

  - src

    - users

      - users.module.ts
      - users.controller.ts
      - users.service.ts
    - todos

      - todos.module.ts
      - todos.controller.ts
      - todos.service.ts
    - app.module.ts
    - app.controller.ts
    - app.service.ts
    - main.ts
- packages

  - shared-nestjs-modules

    - src

      - health

        - health.controller.ts
        - health.service.ts
        - health.module.ts
        - index.ts
      - index.ts`

the issue is that
id param in each users and todos controller is 'undefined' when it is console logged when HealthModule(packages/health) is imported into app.module.ts(apps/bff) but when I deleted HealthModule(packages/health) from app.module.ts, the params in users and todos controller were correctly received. One more weird thing is the param id in health controller was correctly received when I checked with console.log.
It seems the path got mixed up causing this issue but I can't figure out why...

```
app.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TodosModule } from '@todos/todos.module';
import { UsersModule } from '@users/users.module';
import { validate } from '@env/env.validation';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ApiModule } from '@api/api.module';
import { HealthModule } from '@workspace/shared-nestjs-modules';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validate,
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `./src/env/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
    }),
    HealthModule,  // this is the module that seems to cause the problem
    TodosModule,
    UsersModule,
    ApiModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
users.controller.ts

import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, HttpStatus, Param, ParseIntPipe, Patch, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User, UsersService } from './users.service';
import CreateUserDto from './dtos/createUser.dto';
import UpdateUserDto from './dtos/updateUser.dto';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  @Get('/')
  getAllUsers() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    const data = this.usersService.getAllUsers();
    return data;
  }

  @Get(':id')
  getOneUser(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): User {
    console.log('id', id);     // undefined...
    return this.usersService.getOneUser(id);
  }

  @Post('/create')
  createUser(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): User {
    return this.usersService.createUser(createUserDto);
  }

  @Patch(':id')
  patchUser(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number, @Body() updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto): boolean {
    return this.usersService.patchUser(id, updateUserDto);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  deleteUser(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): boolean {
    return this.usersService.deleteUser(id);
  }
}
```

```
todos.controller.ts

import { Body, Controller, Delete, Get, HttpStatus, Param, ParseIntPipe, Patch, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Todo, TodosService } from './todos.service';
import CreateTodoDto from './dtos/createTodo.dto';
import UpdateTodo from './dtos/updateTodo.dto';

@Controller('todos')
export class TodosController {
  constructor(private readonly todosService: TodosService) {}

  @Get('/')
  getAllTodos(): Todo[] {
    return this.todosService.getAllTodos();
  }

  @Get('/:id')
  getOneTodo(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): Todo {
    console.log('id', id)  // undefined...
    return this.todosService.getOneTodo(id);
  }

  @Post('/create')
  createTodo(@Body() createTodoDto: CreateTodoDto): Todo {
    return this.todosService.createTodo(createTodoDto);
  }

  @Patch(':id')
  patchTodo(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number, @Body() updateTodo: UpdateTodo): boolean {
    return this.todosService.patchTodo(id, updateTodo);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  deleteTodo(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number): boolean {
    return this.todosService.deleteTodo(id);
  }
}
```

```
health.controller.ts

import { Controller, Get, HttpStatus, Param, ParseIntPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HealthService } from './health.service';

@Controller('health')
export class HealthController {
  constructor(private readonly healthService: HealthService) {}
  @Get('/')
  getHealthCheck() {
    const healthCheck = this.healthService.getHealthCheck();
    return healthCheck;
  }

  @Get(':id')
  getOneHealthCheck(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number) {
    console.log('id', id);    // but this id param is received correctly
    const healthCheck = this.healthService.getHealthCheck();
    return healthCheck;
  }
}
```

I deleted HealthModule on and off only to have constant issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem

```js
@Module({
  controllers: [AppController, CatsController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    CatsService
  ]
})
```

After changing to Module, the problem was resolved, but I still don't know where the problem is

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    CatsModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
```